# gcc - how to use address sanitizer

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, memory-leaks

I use gcc 4.8.5 on linux. I want to use address sanitizer but it doesn't return any information about the program. Flags:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -Wno-error -g -std=c++11 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address")
SET(CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS} -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address")
```

Linked libraries:

```
target_link_libraries(testcpp asan)
```

The test program with a memory leak:

```
int main()
{
    int *prt = new int;
    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: Compile your program directly on the command line (`cmake`is just confusing us). Show the compilation command in your question.

Comment: BTW GCC4.8 is quite old, and its address sanitizer has progressed a lot (notably in GCC 5 & GCC 6). Try to **use a newer GCC** (GCC 7 if possible)

Comment: My understanding is that you don't need to link against `asan` if you have already specified `-fsanitize=address`. Also, you have to actually run the program it for the sanitizer to run.

Comment: maybe you want `-fsanitize=leak`? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.3.0/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With GCC7 on a recent Debian/Sid/x86-64 I compiled this

```
// file irbis.cc
int main()
{
  int *prt = new int;
  return 0;
}
```

using

```
g++ -fsanitize=address -g3 -std=c++11 irbis.cc -o irbis
```

and at execution of `./irbis` a leak is rightfully detected :

```
=================================================================
==22742==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 4 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f77ea911340 in operator new(unsigned long) 
            (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.4+0xdb340)
    #1 0x55ea91cca81b in main /home/basile/tmp/irbis.cc:4
    #2 0x7f77e9c1f2e0 in __libc_start_main 
            (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x202e0)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 4 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

So **upgrade your GCC compiler** (to at least GCC6). I do know that GCC4.8 had incomplete support for address sanitizer & C++11 (BTW, GCC4.8 is obsolete, and so is GCC5, in november 2017).

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem might be that the main doesn't use `ptr` so it probably was optimized out entierly. Consider this instead:

```
// file irbis.cc
int main()
{
  int *prt = new int;
  return *ptr;
}
```