# OpenMP Segmentation Fault in C++

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, segmentation-fault, openmp, hpc

I have a very straightforward function that counts how many inner entries of an `N` by `N` 2D matrix (represented by a pointer `arr`) is below a certain threshold, and updates a counter `below_threshold` that is passed by reference:

```
void count(float *arr, const int N, const float threshold, int &below_threshold) {
    below_threshold = 0;  // make sure it is reset
    bool comparison;
    float temp;
    
    #pragma omp parallel for shared(arr, N, threshold) private(temp, comparison) reduction(+:below_threshold)
    for (int i = 1; i < N-1; i++)  // count only the inner N-2 rows
    {
        for (int j = 1; j < N-1; j++)  // count only the inner N-2 columns
        {
            temp = *(arr + i*N + j);
            comparison = (temp < threshold);
            below_threshold += comparison;
        }
    }
}
```

When I do not use OpenMP, it runs fine (thus, the allocation and initialization were done correctly already).

When I use OpenMP with an `N` that is less than around 40000, it runs fine.

However, once I start using a larger `N` with OpenMP, it keeps giving me a segmentation fault (I am currently testing with `N = 50000` and would like to eventually get it up to ~100000).

Is there something wrong with this at a software level?

---

P.S. The allocation was done dynamically ( `float *arr = new float [N*N]` ), and here is the code used to randomly initialize the entire matrix, which didn't have any issues with OpenMP with large `N`:

```
void initialize(float *arr, const int N)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            *(arr + i*N + j) = static_cast <float> (rand()) / static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX);
        }
    }

}
```

---

UPDATE:

I have tried changing `i`, `j`, and `N` to `long long int`, and it still has not fixed my segmentation fault. If this was the issue, why has it already worked without OpenMP? It is only once I add `#pragma omp ...` that it fails.

Comment: FYI: [How to generate random numbers in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4287531/10107454).

Comment: In good C++, please don't use `new`? Use `std::vector` or `std:array` instead. That might even have caught this error because may very well be allocating with a negative size. PS C++ also has a better random number generator than what you're using, which additionally can be used thread-safe.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Is std::vector and std::array guaranteed to be memory contiguous?

Comment: Yes, contiguous, if you don't make a `vector<vector<double>>`. An `array<array<double>>` *is* going to be contiguous. I think.

Comment: Changing it to long int doesn't work...

Comment: As mentioned in another comment, `std::ptrdiff_t` from `#include <cstddef>` is more consistent than `long int`. An address sanitizer can be helpful when trying to locate a segfault: [gcc - how to use address sanitizer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47201087/10107454).

Comment: Partially solved, thanks to advice from commenters.

Using `std::ptrdiff_t` did not help at all. I just changed all the pointers to vectors, and now there are no segmentation faults. But I am not completely satisfied...

Thank you @VictorEijkhout

Answer (score 3):

I think, it is because, your value (50000*50000 = 2500000000) reached above `INT_MAX` (2147483647) in c++. As a result, the array access behaviour will be undefined.

So, you should use `UINT_MAX` or some other types that suits with your usecase.

Comment: You should rather use `long int` or `std::int64_t`. `unsigned` will fail for N=100000, while a signed 64 bit integer will work.

Comment: std::ptrdiff_t is the type you are looking for. Signed (not all OpenMP implementations work with unsigned types in their loops), and not unnecessarily large on 32 bit systems. Also long int on Windows is 32 bit so that wouldn't work.

Comment: @paleonix This doesn't fix my segmentation fault...