C++ google test (gtest) unit test fails occasionally on a GitLab pipeline
g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-22)

A unit google test (gtest) test fails occasionally with a Segmentation fault on a GitLab CI/CD pipeline running in a docker dev-container. The unit test job ends with the following lines:
[  PASSED  ] 12 tests.
/usr/bin/bash: line 234:    14 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./build/test/unit_test_Algorithms
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

I hit the GitLab job retry button and the unit test passes.
For this type of error, I WAG some pointer memory issue, or dtor cleanup problem.
I don't think I can get valgrind setup in the pipeline (but I'll confirm with the platform team).  I could instrument all ctor/dtor's to make sure I have the same number of dtors as ctors if you think that would help. There are multiple authors of these tests. The seg fault occurred before my one contribution.
Does the fact that the seg fault occurs only after the 12 tests passed mean that the seg fault is coming from gtest itself?
I am not hearing of seg fault issues from the integration and test team, so it appears this may be isolated to the unit test. Can you advise what any steps I should take to try to isolate and fix this problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47201087/gcc-how-to-use-address-sanitizer
